TSA PreCheck Application via CLEAR: 'No Status Found' After 43 Days—Is This Normal?
I applied for TSA PreCheck through CLEAR 43 days ago and immediately received confirmation that my application had been received. However, when I try to check the status using the TSA’s official status link (https://tsaenrollmentbyidemia.tsa.dhs.gov/workflows?workflow=service-status&servicecode=11115V), I see the message: 'No status found.'
I called 855-DHS-UES1 (855-347-8371) for clarification, and an officer mentioned that this is normal because my application was submitted via CLEAR.
Has anyone else experienced this issue when applying through CLEAR? If so, how long did it take to receive an update on your application status, and is there anything else I should do to follow up?

Received approval on 61st day of the application. Apparently, "No status found" does not mean automatically there is no record.

Thanks for coming back to tell us how it went! Feel free to accept your own answer.
